# How to create a Java SerializedLambda from a Kotlin lambda?

Tags: java, kotlin, jinq

If I have a Kotlin lambda, eg.

```
{ a -> a.b }
```

...I know this can be passed into a Java Serializable interface, eg:

```
interface I extends Serializable {
  public int f(T t);
}
```

However, the actual *type* of the lambda is not SerializedLambda.

Is it possible to create a genuine SerializedLambda from a Kotlin lambda?

(The reason is for compatibility with JINQ)

Comment: [Duplicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40064479/jinq-in-kotlin-how-to-convert-lambda-into-java-serializedlambda)

Comment: Indeed it is a duplicate, but the answer is incorrect.